# Writing tuple output to a text file

Tags: python, text

Is it possible to write my output tuple to a text file? I am using following code to get text between two strings as write them to a text file:

```
def format_file(file, start, end):
    f = open('C:\TEMP\Test.txt', 'r').read()
    return tuple(x for x in ''.join(f.split(start)).replace('\n', '').split(end) if x != '')

print (format_file('XYZ', 'Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final', 'Event Brief of Q1 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final'))
file = open('C:\TEMP\out.txt', 'w')
file.write(format_file('XYZ', 'Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final', 'Event Brief of Q1 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final'))
```

But I keep getting following error:TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple.
When I try to return output as a string instead of a tuple I get a blank file. I would really appreciate any help on this one.

here is my input file text:

```
Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final




OPERATOR: From Piper Jaffray, we'll hear from Gene Munster.

GENE MUNSTER, ANALYST, PIPER JAFFRAY & CO.: Good afternoon. Tim, can you talk a little bit about the iPhone ASP trends, and specifically you mentioned that the SE is going to impact, but how are you thinking about the aspirational market share that's out there, and your actual market share, and using price to close that gap? Is it just the SE or could there be other iPhone models that will be discounted, to try to be more aggressive in emerging markets?

And one for Luca. Can you talk a little bit about the services segment, in terms of what piece of the services is driving growth, and maybe a little bit about the profitability on a net basis versus the growth basis that you have referred to in the past. Thanks.

TIM COOK: I think the SE is attracting two types of customers. One is customers that wanted the latest technology, but wanted it in a more compact package. And we clearly see even more people than we thought in that category.

Secondly, it's attracting people aspire to own an iPhone, but couldn't quite stretch to the entry price of the iPhone, and we've established a new entry. I think both of these markets are very, very important to us, and we are really excited about where it can take us. I do think that we will be really happy with the new to iPhone customers that we see from here, because of the early returns we've had. We are currently supply constrained, but we'll be able to work our way out of this at some point. But it's great to see the overwhelming demand for it. I will let Luca comment on the ASPs.

LUCA MAESTRI: On the ASPs, Gene we mentioned that we were going to be down sequentially, and this is really the combination of two factors. So when we go from the March quarter to the June quarter, is the fact that we are having the SE entering the mix, and that obviously is going to have a downward pressure on ASP, and also this channel inventory reduction that we have talked about, obviously the channel inventory reduction will come from higher-end models, and that is also affecting the sequential trend on ASPs.

The question on services, when we look at our services business, obviously growing very well across the board. The biggest element, and the part of the services business that is growing very well, we mentioned 35%, is the App Store. It's interesting for us that our music business, which had been declining for a number of quarters, now that we have both a download model and a streaming model, we have now hit an inflection point, and we believe that this would be the bottom, and we can start growing from there over time.

We have many other services businesses that are doing very well, we have an iCloud business that is growing very quickly. Faster than the App Store, from a much lower base but I think it's important for us as we continue to develop these businesses. Tim have talked about Apple Pay. It doesn't provide a meaningful financial contribution at this point, but as we look at the amount of transactions that go into Apple Pay right now, and we think ahead for the long-term, that could be an interesting business for us, as well.

From a profitability standpoint, we have mentioned last time that when you look at it on a gross basis, so in terms of purchase value of these services, the profitability of the business is similar to Company average. Of course, when you met out the amount that is paid to developers, and you look at it, in terms of what is reported in our P&L, obviously that business has a profitability that is higher than Company average. We don't get into the specifics of specific products or services, but it is very clear it is significantly higher than Company average.

GENE MUNSTER: Thank you.

NANCY PAXTON: Thanks, Gene. Could we have the next question please?

OPERATOR: Katy Huberty with Morgan Stanley.

KATY HUBERTY, ANALYST, MORGAN STANLEY: Yes, thank you. First for Luca. This is the worst gross margin guide in a year and a half or so, and over the last couple of quarters, you have talked about number of tailwinds including component cost, the lower accounting deferrals that went into effect in September. You just mentioned the services margins are above corporate average. So the question is, are some of those tailwinds winding down? Or is a significant guide down in gross margin for the June quarter entirely related to volume and the 5 SE? And then I have a follow-up for Tim.

LUCA MAESTRI: Katy, clearly the commodity environment remains quite favorable, and we continue to expect cost improvements. The other dynamics that you have mentioned are still there, obviously what is different, and particularly as we look at it on a sequential basis coming out of the March quarter, we would have loss of leverage, and that obviously is going to have a negative impact on margins. The other factor that's important to keep in mind is this different mix of products.

Particularly when you look at iPhone, what I was mentioning to Gene earlier, I think we've got a couple of things that are affecting not only ASPs, but obviously, they also affects margins. And it's the fact that we have a channel inventory reduction at the top end of the range, and we've got the introduction of the iPhone SE at the entry level of the range. And so when you take into account those factors, those are the big elements that drive our guidance range right now.

KATY HUBERTY: Okay. Thank you. And that a question for Tim, appreciate the optimism around longer-term iPhone unit growth, but with developed market penetration in anywhere from 60% to 80%, the growth is going to have to come from new markets. You talked about India. Could you just spend a little bit more time on that market? What are some of the hurdles you have to overcome, for that to be a larger part of the business? When we expect Apple to have more distribution, and specifically your own stores in that country? Thanks.

TIM COOK: Katy, in the short term, let me just make a couple of comments on the developed markets, just to make sure this is clear. If you look at our installed base of iPhone today versus two years ago, it's increased by 80%. When you think about upgrade cycles, upgrade cycles would have varying rates on it. As I talked about on the comments, the iPhone 6s rate, upgrade rate is slightly higher than the iPhone 5s, but lower than the iPhone 6.

But the other multiplier in that equation is obviously the size of the installed base. The net of the idea is that I think there's still really, really good business in the developed markets, so I wouldn't want to write those off. It's our job to come up with great products that people desire, and also to continue to attract over Android switchers. With our worldwide share there's still quite a bit of room in the developed markets, as well.

From an India point of view, if you look at India, and each country has a different story a bit, but the things that have held not only us back, perhaps, but some others as well, is that the LTE rollout with India just really begins this year. So we will begin to see some really good networks coming on in India. That will unleash the power and capability of the iPhone, in a way that an older network, 2.5G or even some 3G networks, would not do. The infrastructure is one key one, and the second one is building the channel out.

Unlike the US as an example, where the carriers in the US sell the vast majority of phones that are sold in the United States, in India, the carriers in general sell virtually no phones, and it is out in retail, and retail is many, many different small shops. We've been in the process. It's not something we just started in the last few weeks.

We've been working in India now for a couple of years or more, but we've been working with great energy over the last 18 months or so, and I am encouraged by the results that we're beginning to see there, and believe there's a lot, lot more there. It is already the third largest smart phone market in the world, but because the smart phones that are working there are low-end, primarily because of the network and the economics, the market potential has not been as great there. I view India as where China was maybe 7 to 10 years ago from that point of view. I think there's a really great opportunity there.

NANCY PAXTON: Thank you, Katy. Could we have the next question please?

OPERATOR: We will go to Toni Sacconaghi with Bernstein.

TONI SACCONAGHI, ANALYST, BERNSTEIN: I have one, and then a follow-up, as well. My sense is that you talked about adjusting for the changes in channel inventory, that you are guiding for relatively normal sequential growth. And I think if you do the math it's probably the same or perhaps a touch worse in terms of iPhone unit growth sequentially, relative to normal seasonality between fiscal Q2 and Q3. I guess the question is, given that you should be entering new markets and you should see pronounced elasticity from the SE device, why wouldn't we be seeing something that was dramatically above normal seasonal, in terms of iPhone revenues and units for this quarter?

Maybe you could push back on me, but I can't help thinking that when Apple introduced the iPad Mini in a similar move, to move down market, there was great growth for one quarter, and the iPad never grew again and margins and ASPs went down. It looks like you are introducing the SE, and at least on a sequential basis, you not calling for any uplift, even adjusting for channel inventory, and ASPs I presume will go down and certainly it's impacting gross margins as you've guided to. Could you respond to, A, why you're not seeing the elasticity, and B, is the analogy with the iPad mini completely misplaced?

TIM COOK: Toni, it's Tim. Let me see if I can address your question. The channel inventory reduction that Luca referred to, the vast, vast majority of that is in iPhone. That would affect the unit compare that you maybe thinking about. The iPhone SE, we are thrilled with the response that we've seen on it.

It is clear that there is a demand there, even much beyond what we thought, and so that is really why we have the constraint that we have. Do I think it will be like the iPad Mini? No, I don't think so. I don't see that.

I think the tablet market in general, one of the challenges with the tablet market is that the replacement cycle is materially different than in the smart phone market. As you probably know, we haven't had an issue in customer satisfaction on the iPad. It is incredibly high, and we haven't had an issue with usage of the iPad. The usage is incredibly high.

But the consumer behavior there is you tend to hold on for very long period of time, before an upgrade. We continue to be very optimistic on the iPad business, and as I have said in my remarks, we believe we are going to have the best compare for iPad revenue this quarter that we have quite some time. We will report back in July on that one, but I think iPhone has a particularly different kind of cycle to it than the tablet market.

TONI SACCONAGHI: Okay, and if I could follow-up, Tim. You alluded to replacement cycles and differences between the iPad and the iPhone. My sense was, when you were going through the iPhone 6 cycle, was that you had commented that the upgrade cycle was not materially different. I think your characterization was that it accelerated a bit in the US, but international had grown to be a bigger part of your business, and replacement cycles there were typically a little bit longer. I'm wondering if it was only a modest difference between the 5s and the 6, how big a difference are we really seeing in terms of replacement cycles across the last three generations, and maybe you could help us, if the replacement cycle was flat this year relative to what you saw last year, how different would your results have been this quarter in the first half?

TIM COOK: There's a lot there. Let me just say I don't recall saying the things that you said I said about the upgrade cycle, so let me get that out of the way. Now let me describe without the specific numbers, the iPhone 6s upgrade cycle that we have measured for the first half of this year, so the first six months of our fiscal year to be precise, is slightly better than the rate that we saw with the iPhone 5s two years ago, but it's lower than the iPhone 6. I don't mean just a hair lower, it's a lot lower.

Without giving you exact numbers, if we would have the same rate on 6s that we did 6, there would -- it will be time for a huge party. It would be a huge difference. The great news from my point of view is, I think we are strategically positioned very well, because we have announced the SE, we are attracting customers that we previously didn't attract. That's really great, and this tough compare eventually isn't the benchmark. The install base is up 80% over the last two years, and so all of those I think bode well, and the switcher comments I made earlier, I wouldn't underestimate that, because that's very important for us in every geography. Thanks for the question.

NANCY PAXTON: Thanks, Toni. Can we have the next question please?

OPERATOR: From Cross Research Group, we'll hear from Shannon Cross.

SHANNON CROSS, ANALYST, CROSS RESEARCH: I have a couple of questions. One, Tim, can you talk a bit about what's going on in China? The greater China revenue I think was down 26%. You did talk about mainland China, but if you could talk about some of the trends you're seeing there, and how you think it's playing out, and maybe your thoughts on SE adoption within China as well.

TIM COOK: Shannon, thanks for the question. If you take greater China, we include Taiwan, Hong Kong, and mainland China in the greater China segment that you see reported on your data sheet. The vast majority of the weakness in the greater China region sits in Hong Kong, and our perspective on that is, it's a combination of the Hong Kong dollar being pegged to the US dollar, and therefore it carries the burden of the strength of the US dollar, and that has driven tourism, international shopping and trading down significantly compared to what it was in the year ago.

If you look at mainland China, which is one that I am personally very focused on, we are down 11% in mainland China, on a reported basis. On a constant currency basis, we are only down 7%, and the way that we really look at the health or underlying demand is look at sell-through, and if you look at there, we were down 5%. Keep in mind that is down 5% on comp a year ago that was up 81%.

As I back up from this and look at the larger picture, I think China is not weak, as has been talked about. I see China as -- may not have the wind at our backs that we once did, but it's a lot more stable than what I think is the common view of it. We remain really optimistic on China. We opened seven stores there during the quarter.

We are now at 35. We will open 5 more this quarter to achieve 40, which we had talked about before. And the LTE adoption continues to rise there, but it's got a long way ahead of it. And so we continue to be really optimistic about it, and just would ask folks to look underneath the numbers at the details in them before concluding anything. Thanks for the question.

SHANNON CROSS: Thanks. My second question is with regard to OpEx leverage, or thinking about when I look at the revenue, your revenue is below our expectations but OpEx is pretty much in line. So how are you thinking about potential for leverage, cost containment, maybe when macro is bad and revenue is under pressure, and how are you juggling that versus the required investment you need to go forward?

LUCA MAESTRI: It is Luca. Of course, we think about it. We think about it a lot, and so when you look at our results, for example, our OpEx for the quarter, for the March quarter was up 10%, which is the lowest rate that you have seen in years. And when you look within OpEx, you actually see two different dynamics. You see continued significant investments in research and development, because we really believe that's the future of the Company.

We continue to invest in initiatives and projects ahead of revenue. We had a much broader portfolio that we used to have. We do much more in-house technology development than we used to do a few years ago, which we think is a great investment for us to make. And so that parts we didn't need to protect, and we want to continue to invest in the business, right?

And then when you look at our SG&A portion of OpEx for the March quarter, it was actually down slightly. So obviously we think about it, and of course we look at our revenue trends, and we take measures accordingly. When you look at the guidance that we provided for the June quarter, that 10% year-over-year increase that I mentioned to you for the March quarter goes down to a range of 7% to 9% up, and again, the focus is on making investments in Road and continuing to run SG&A extremely tightly, and in a very disciplined way.

As you know, our E2R, expense to revenue ratio, is around 10%. It's something that we are very proud of, it's a number that is incredibly competitive in our industry, and we want to continue to keep it that way. At the same time, we don't want to under-invest in the business.

SHANNON CROSS: Thank you.

NANCY PAXTON: Thank you, Shannon. Could we have the next question please?

OPERATOR: From UBS we hear from Steve Milunovich.

STEVE MILUNOVICH, ANALYST, UBS: Tim, I first wanted to ask you about services and how do you view services? You've obviously highlighted it the last two quarters. Do you view it going forward as a primary driver of earnings, or do you view it, and you mentioned platforms in terms of your operating systems, which I would agree with. In that scenario I would argue it's more a supporter of the ecosystem, and a supporter of the hardware margins over time, and therefore somewhat subservient to hardware. It's great that it's growing, but longer-term, I would view its role as more creating an ecosystem that supports the high margins on the hardware, as opposed to independently driving earnings. How do you think about it?

TIM COOK: The most important thing for us, Steve, is that we want to have a great customer experience, so overwhelmingly, the thing that drives us are to embark on services that help that, and become a part of the ecosystem. The reality is that in doing so, we have developed a very large and profitable business in the services area, and so we felt last quarter and working up to that, that we should pull back the curtain so that people could -- our investors could see the services business, both in terms of the scale of it, and the growth of it. As we said earlier, the purchase value of the installed base services grew by 27% during the quarter, which was an acceleration over the previous quarter, and the value of it hit -- was just shy of $10 billion. It's huge, and we felt it was important to spell that out.

STEVE MILUNOVICH: Okay, and then going back to the upgrades of the installed base, you have clearly mentioned that you've pulled forward some demand, which makes sense, but there does seem to be a lengthening of the upgrade cycle, particularly in the US. AT&T and Verizon have talked about that. Investors I think perceive that maybe the marginal improvements on the phone might be less currently, and could be less going forward. At the same time, I think you just announced that you can get the upgrade program online, which I guess potentially could shorten it. Do you believe that upgrade cycles are currently lengthening, and can continue to do so?

TIM COOK: What we've seen is that it depends on what you compare it to. If you compare to the 5s, what we are seeing is the upgrade rate today is slightly higher, or that there are more people upgrading, if you will, in a similar time period, in terms of a rate, than the 5s. But if you compare to 6, you would clearly arrive at the opposite conclusion. I think it depends on people's reference points, and we thought it very important in this call to be very clear and transparent about what we're seeing. I think in retrospect, you could look at it and say, maybe the appropriate measure is more to the 5s, and I think everybody intuitively thought that the upgrades were accelerated with the 6, and in retrospect, when you look at the periods, they clearly were.

STEVE MILUNOVICH: Thank you.

NANCY PAXTON: Thanks, Steve. Could we have our next question, please?

OPERATOR: We will go to Rod Hall with JPMorgan.

ROD HALL, ANALYST, JPMORGAN: Yes, thanks for fitting me in. I wanted to start with a general, more general question. I guess, Tim, this one is aimed at you. As you think about where you thought things were going to head last quarter, when you reported to us, and how it's changed this quarter, obviously it's kind of a disappointing demand environment. Can you just help us understand what maybe the top two or three things are that have changed? And so as we walk away from this, we understand what the differences are, and what the direction of change is? Then I have a follow-up.

TIM COOK: I think you're probably indirectly asking about our trough comment, if you will, from last quarter. And when we made that, we did not contemplate or comprehend that we were going to make a $2 billion-plus reduction in channel inventory during this quarter. So if you factor that in and look at true customer demand, which is the way that we look at internally, I think you'll find a much more reasonable comparison.

ROD HALL: Okay, great. Thank you. And then for my follow-up, I wanted to ask you about the tax situation a little bit. Treasury obviously has made some rule changes, and I wonder, maybe if Luca, you could comment on what the impact to Apple from those is, if anything? and Tim, maybe more broadly how you see the tax situation for Apple looking forward? Thanks.

LUCA MAESTRI: Yes, Rod, these are new regulations, and we are in the processing of assessing them. Frankly from first read, we don't anticipate that they are going to have any material impact on our tax situation. Some of them relate to inversion transactions, obviously that's not an issue for us. Some of them are around internal debt financing, which is not something that we use, so we don't expect any issue there.

As you know, we are the largest US taxpayer by a wide margin, and we already pay full US tax on all the profits from the sales that we make in the United States, so we don't expect them to have any impact on us on tax reform. I will let Tim continue to provide more color, but we've been strong advocates for comprehensive corporate tax reform in this country. We continue to do that. We think a reform of the tax code would have significant benefits for the entire US economy, and we remain optimistic that we are going to get to a point where we can see that tax reform enacted. At that point in time, of course, we would have much more flexibility around optimizing our capital structure, and around providing more return of capital to our investors.

TIM COOK: The only thing I would add, Rod, is I think there are a growing number of people in both parties that would like to see comprehensive reform, and so I'm optimistic that it will occur. It's just a matter of when and that's difficult to say. But I think most people do recognize that it is in the US's interest to do this.

ROD HALL: Great, thanks.

NANCY PAXTON: Thank you, Rod. A replay of today's call will be available for two weeks as a podcast on the iTunes Store, as webcast on Apple.com/investor and via telephone. And the numbers for the telephone replay are 888-203-1112, or 719-457-0820, and please enter confirmation code 7495552. These replays will be available by approximately 5:00 PM Pacific time today.

Members of the press with additional questions can contact Kristin Huguet at 408-974-2414, and financial analysts can contact Joan Hoover or me with additional questions. Joan is at 408-974-4570, and I am at 408-974-5420. Thanks again for joining us.

OPERATOR: Ladies and gentlemen, that does conclude today's presentation. We do thank everyone for your participation.

[Thomson Financial reserves the right to make changes to documents, content, or other information on this web site without obligation to notify any person of such changes.

In the conference calls upon which Event Transcripts are based, companies may make projections or other forward-looking statements regarding a variety of items. Such forward-looking statements are based upon current expectations and involve risks and uncertainties. Actual results may differ materially from those stated in any forward-looking statement based on a number of important factors and risks, which are more specifically identified in the companies' most recent SEC filings. Although the companies may indicate and believe that the assumptions underlying the forward-looking statements are reasonable, any of the assumptions could prove inaccurate or incorrect and, therefore, there can be no assurance that the results contemplated in the forward-looking statements will be realized.

THE INFORMATION CONTAINED IN EVENT TRANSCRIPTS IS A TEXTUAL REPRESENTATION OF THE APPLICABLE COMPANY'S CONFERENCE CALL AND WHILE EFFORTS ARE MADE TO PROVIDE AN ACCURATE TRANSCRIPTION, THERE MAY BE MATERIAL ERRORS, OMISSIONS, OR INACCURACIES IN THE REPORTING OF THE SUBSTANCE OF THE CONFERENCE CALLS. IN NO WAY DOES THOMSON FINANCIAL OR THE APPLICABLE COMPANY OR THE APPLICABLE COMPANY ASSUME ANY RESPONSIBILITY FOR ANY INVESTMENT OR OTHER DECISIONS MADE BASED UPON THE INFORMATION PROVIDED ON THIS WEB SITE OR IN ANY EVENT TRANSCRIPT. USERS ARE ADVISED TO REVIEW THE APPLICABLE COMPANY'S CONFERENCE CALL ITSELF AND THE APPLICABLE COMPANY'S SEC FILINGS BEFORE MAKING ANY INVESTMENT OR OTHER DECISIONS.]



LOAD-DATE: April 29, 2016



LANGUAGE: ENGLISH



TRANSCRIPT: 042616a5987433.733



PUBLICATION-TYPE: Transcript



Copyright 2016 CQ-Roll Call, Inc.
All Rights Reserved

Copyright 2016 CCBN, Inc.





4 of 9 DOCUMENTS




FD (Fair Disclosure) Wire



January 26, 2016 Tuesday



Event Brief of Q1 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final
```

and the output I am expecting is everthing between 'Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final' and 'Event Brief of Q1 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final' in a text file.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks very much like you are using your `format_file` function inappropriately.

Comment: Thanks Nicarus, what should be the proper format for this?

Comment: You created the function or did you get the snippet from elsewhere?

Comment: I got looked at some of the posts and then created it. thank you.

Comment: It may be helpful to update your question with an example of the output that you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks again, I have edited my post. I couldn't figure out a way to attach a file to my post in stackoverflow and hence copied and pasted it with the post. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did your try converting your tuple into a string and writing to the file?

```
    s = str('XYZ', 'Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final', 'Event Brief of Q1 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final')
    file.write(s)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I did try that and I get a black output file when I try to use it.